# Git fetch origin vs git fetch --all

Tags: git, git-fetch

What is the difference between the following git commands?

```
git fetch origin
```

and

```
git fetch --all
```

Running them from the command line looks like they do the same thing.

Comment: the documentation you reference is confusing to a newer git command line user like myself. I was looking for a clear concise answer, which the other posters helped with greatly

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`git fetch origin` fetch data only from `origin`, and `git fetch --all` fetch data from all remotes (`origin` is one of them)

Comment: Also, `git fetch` by itself will use `git fetch origin` by default. From the docs: *"When no remote is specified, by default the origin remote will be used, unless there’s an upstream branch configured for the current branch."*

Answer (score 12):

```
git fetch --all
```

> ***`--all`***
>     Fetch all remotes.

If you want to get all the data and on the same time also to remove the
deleted data add the `--prune` flag

```
# Fetch all data, remove dangling objects and pack you repository
git fetch --all --prune=now
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'deleted data'? Do you mean if upstream removed an image, then by doing `git fetch --all --prune` the image would be removed from my local?

Comment: @Honey It means that local information about `origin/some-branch` etc will be deleted. It does _not_ affect your working copy in any way, only your local copy of the remote repository.

Answer (score 6):

Your repository may have one remote point known by alias as 'origin', but you may also have other remotes configured. The latter command would fetch from them all.

More in [the docs for fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch).

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `git fetch` and `git fetch origin` are the same.
And they differ from [`git fetch --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---all), which fetches *all* the remotes.

But, with Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f033388b0f1f633706ef0c1033b32e52f1d5df72/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> learned to pay attention to `fetch.all` configuration variable, which pretends as if "`--all`" was passed from the command line when no remote parameter was given.

See [commit 39487a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39487a1510fcdbb4124882f531a077dbdfe1ef60) (08 Jan 2024) by [Tamino Bauknecht (`taminob`)](https://github.com/taminob).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f033388](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f033388b0f1f633706ef0c1033b32e52f1d5df72), 19 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39487a1510fcdbb4124882f531a077dbdfe1ef60): add new config option fetch.all
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tamino Bauknecht</sup>

> Introduce a boolean configuration option fetch.all which allows to fetch all available remotes by default.
> The config option can be overridden by explicitly specifying a remote or by using --no-all.
> The behavior for `--all` is unchanged and calling [`git-fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/39487a1510fcdbb4124882f531a077dbdfe1ef60/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> with `--all` and a remote will still result in an error.
>
> Additionally, describe the configuration variable in the config documentation and implement new tests to cover the expected behavior.
> Also [`add --no-all`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/39487a1510fcdbb4124882f531a077dbdfe1ef60/Documentation/git-add.txt#L143)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---no-all))</sup> to the command-line documentation of git-fetch.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/39487a1510fcdbb4124882f531a077dbdfe1ef60/Documentation/config/fetch.txt#L53-L58):

> ### `fetch.all`
>
> If true, fetch will attempt to update all available remotes.
> This behavior can be overridden by passing `--no-all` or by
> explicitly specifying one or more remote(s) to fetch from.
> Defaults to false.

`fetch-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/39487a1510fcdbb4124882f531a077dbdfe1ef60/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L1-L3):

> ### `--[no-]all`
>
> Fetch all remotes. This overrides the configuration variable
> `fetch.all`.

So... `git fetch` and `git fetch --all` could be the same(!) if `git config fetch.all true` was done first.